# Laravel eloquent data from related tabel of related tabel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-7

I was wondering if it is possible to select the data from a table that is related with a related table. I'll add an image to make it more clear:
[image]

What I currently have is:
`Sensor::all()->with('sensor_types', 'sensor_triggers')->get();`

This returns the `sensors`, `sensor_types`, and `sensor_triggers` table. I also want to get the `value_types` together with `sensor_types`
As far as I could find i can only select data from a directly related database and not something like a 'double with' like `sensors with sensor_types with value_types`

I was wondering if there is a way to do this.
Using Laravel 7.2.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the relation of the child relation you can use dot

```
Sensor::all()->with('sensor_types.value_types', 'sensor_triggers')->get();
```